# Google index hash url - What about the backlinks?

Tags: google, backlinks, hash

We started a project where all the backlinks go to an overlay URL with hash. So it's possible to show interesting content for publishers on the site we want to build backlinks.

Today we saw that google index hash URLs also.

For example:

- `example.com#publisher-article-1`
- `example.com#publisher-article-2`

All the backlinks should go to example.com

Now everything changes because google also index URLs with hash in it.

Is there any way to not lose those links?

Comment: It sounds like you were incorrectly using a [linking scheme](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en) to try to pump up your base domain.   You are lucky that Google never penalized your site for it.  Now that Google is doing the right thing and treating the links as links to the specific content, you shouldn't have a problem.  Things are working as they should.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution i can think of is to delete those pages so ones with a # in it then  redirect them to the root domain and you should retain most of the link juice

Comment: It is not possible to redirect hash URLs.   Redirects are done on the server side but the hash portion of URLs is client side only.   Servers never even see the URL hash.

Comment: You could possibly add a logic on the page e.g. with php, that looks at the full url and then perform a redirect. I haven't tried this myself but it should be possible in theory... I think.